# Битрикс получить адрес пункта самовывоза заказа через api

Tags: php, битрикс

Версия Битрикс 18.5.
При оформлении заказа в корзине можно выбрать пункт самовывоза:

[image: Выбор пунктов самовывоза в корзине Битрикс]

В панели администрирования выбранный пункт самовывоза отображается в виде:
[image: Вывод пункта самовывоза в админке Битрикс]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить данные пункта самовывоза по api, например, по id заказа?

Пытался получить через:

```
<?php
// способ 1
use Bitrix\Sale;
$order = Sale\Order::load($orderID);

// способ 2
$arOrder = CSaleOrder::GetByID($orderID);

// способ 3
$arOrderProps = CSaleOrderPropsValue::GetOrderProps($orderID);
```

Но не в одном из полученном массиве не получилось найти данные по пункту самовывоза заказа.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Написал сам, для моей редакции работает. 
Мне необходимо было получить только адрес, для других данных можете доработать метод под свои нужды:

```
/**
 * Получение адреса пункта самовывоза по id заказа
 * @param int $order_id Id заказа со способом доставки "самовывоз"
 * @return bool
 */
function order_get_selfdelivery_address($order_id)
{
    // получаем id пункта самовывоза заказа
    try {
        $order = \Bitrix\Sale\Order::load($order_id);
    } catch (\Bitrix\Main\ArgumentNullException|\Bitrix\Main\NotImplementedException $e) {
        return false;
    }

    $store_id = null;
    foreach ($order->getShipmentCollection() as $s) {
        /** @var \Bitrix\Sale\Shipment $s */
        $store_id = $s->getStoreId();
        if ($store_id) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$store_id) {
        return false;
    }

    // получаем адрес пункта самовывоза по id
    $connection = \Bitrix\Main\Application::getConnection();
    $sql = '
        SELECT ADDRESS 
        FROM b_catalog_store
        WHERE id = ' . (int)$store_id . '
    ';
    $store = $connection->query($sql)->fetch();
    if (!$store) {
        return false;
    }

    return $store['ADDRESS'];
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, как вам удалось этот блок "самовывоз" вообще вывести? У меня только пункт доставка. Самовывоза никакого нет

Answer (score -1):

```
public static function getSelectedStore($orderId)
{
    $arStore = [];
    $order = \Bitrix\Sale\Order::load($orderId);
    $shipments = $order->getShipmentCollection();
    foreach ($shipments as $shipment) {
        if (!$shipment->isSystem()) {
            $storeId = $shipment->getStoreId();
            if ($storeId > 0) {
                $dbList = \CCatalogStore::GetList(
                    array("ID" => "DESC"),
                    array("ID" => $storeId),
                    false,
                    false,
                    array("ID", "ADDRESS", "DESCRIPTION")
                );
                if ($store = $dbList->Fetch()) {
                    $arStore = $store;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $arStore;
}
```